# How do i select a 2x2 matrix from 3x3 matrix using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
A=np.array([[2.3,6,5.7],
            [0,4.7,10],
            [0,2,13.4]])

B=A[[1,2],[1,2]]  #i ended up getting 2 elements instead of 2x2 matrix

print(B)
```

B = ([4.7,13.4]) *This is not the answer i want*

i am doing **Householder Transformation** second part, i have zerorised the bottom left, please guide me how to tell python to get the following 2x2 matrix. Below is the answer that i want.

B = ([[4.7,10],
[2,13.4]])

Comment: `B=A[[[1],[2]], [1,2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A=np.array([[2.3,6,5.7],
        [0,4.7,10],
        [0,2,13.4]])

B = A[1:3, 1:3]
print(B)
```

[Indexing — NumPy v1.20 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) might help you to understand how indexing works in numpy.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> A[1:, 1:]
array([[ 4.7, 10. ],
       [ 2. , 13.4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select any `2x2` square from the top left corner

```
def select2x2(A, idx):
    x,y = idx
    return A[np.r_[x:x+2][:,None], np.r_[y:y+2][None,:]]
```

Test:

```
A=np.array([[2.3,6,5.7],
            [0,4.7,10],
            [0,2,13.4]])
select2x2(A, (1,1))
```

output:

```
array([[ 4.7, 10. ],
       [ 2. , 13.4]])
```